# I want to create an iPhone card game. Should I use Core animation or Cocoa 2D?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an iPhone card game. What should I use: Core animation or Cocoa 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use UIKit elements on your app, such as textfield, label. I would recommend Core Animation. Now, if you are going to explore more complex animations that cannot be achieved by using core animation, then go for COCOS2d.

Comment: i want to develop card game and in it some of animation are there so which is best for me.

Comment: I would start with core animation. You can create several effects using it. Download this project example. It will give you a figure. https://github.com/neror/CA360

Comment: ya i already download it and it really helped me lot but in that no programmed for multiple animation with one array that's why i searching for it.

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at [Core Animation Transaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html)

Comment: Here's another example: [Orbiting planet example](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1)

Comment: Thank' edmar. it such helped to me or developing the code i will check it and try to develop the game animation.